# Getting cluster centers and their values in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, clustering, grid-cluster

I want to do clustering of an area in Google Earth Engine using temperature and precipitation (maybe more variables in the future). I have got the clustering result, but still want to know the temperature and precipitation value of each cluster center.

If "ee.Clusterer.wekaMeans" cannot achieve that, is there any other way to achieve it with Google Earth Engine?

Here are codes:

```
//Import T and Prcp data.
var eramon = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/MONTHLY_AGGR")
          .filterDate("2002-01-01","2021-01-01")
          .select(["temperature_2m","total_precipitation_sum"])
          .mean()
          .clip(region);

// Make the training dataset.
var training = eramon.sample({
    region: region,
    scale: 11132,
    numPixels: 5000
});

// Instantiate the clusterer and train it.
var clusterer = ee.Clusterer.wekaKMeans(10,0).train(training);

// Cluster the eramon using the trained clusterer.
var result = eramon.cluster(clusterer);

// Then how to get the T and Prcp values of each cluster centers (There have been 10 categories)
```

Answer (score 1):

Cluster the training data, then reduce it with a mean reducer, grouping on clusters.

```
var properties = eramon.bandNames().add("cluster")
var means = training.cluster(clusterer)
    .reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.mean().repeat(2).group(2), properties)
```

Comment: Hei, I got this error:

    Dictionary (Error)
    Collection.reduceColumns: Need 3 inputs for 
    Reducer.group(Reducer.repeat(Reducer.mean)), got 13.