# Getting cluster centers of entire "result" image (final gridded clustered image)

Tags: google-earth-engine, clustering, grid-cluster

I have got the cluster centers by clustering the training data. Click [How to get cluster centers and their values in Google Earth Engine?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/455446) to review the relevant question. I still wonder whether the cluster centers obtained in this way are only based on the data in the "training" FeatureCollection because "training" only contains at most 5000 pixels, but my region of insterest or the "result" image covers 100000 pixels.

What is the difference between the cluster centers of "tranining" and "result"?

What I should do If I want to get the cluster centers of the whole "result" image (the final gridded clustered image)?

Here are codes:

```
//Import T and Prcp data.
var eramon = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/MONTHLY_AGGR")
          .filterDate("2002-01-01","2021-01-01")
          .select(["temperature_2m","total_precipitation_sum"])
          .mean()
          .clip(region);

// Make the training dataset.
var training = eramon.sample({
    region: region,
    scale: 11132,
    numPixels: 5000
});

// Instantiate the clusterer and train it.
var clusterer = ee.Clusterer.wekaKMeans(10,0).train(training);

// Get the cluster centers by clustering the training data.
var properties = eramon.bandNames().add("cluster")
var means = training.cluster(clusterer)
    .reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.mean().repeat(2).group(2), properties)

// Cluster the eramon using the trained clusterer and then get the final 
// gridded clustered image.
var result = eramon.cluster(clusterer);
```

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, clarify what you mean by cluster centers. If you put `result` on a map (`Map.addLayer(result.randomVisualizer())`), you'll notice that some KMeans clusters does not have all their pixels connected. So it doesn't really make sense to talk about center of the KMeans clusters. On the other hand, many pixels from a KMeans cluster are typically clustered together. If these are the clusters you want the center of, that makes sense.

The `tranining` is simply a random sample of `eramon`. They are not centers.

The below is a stab at extracting the cluster centers. It uses `reduceToVectors()` to turn your image into a feature collection. This works since it's such a low-res dataset and you don't end up with so many pixels. Then the centroid of each feature is extracted. There is no guarantee that the centroid actually is within the cluster. It depends on the shape of the cluster. Perhaps there's a more clever way to determine the center.

```
var vectors = result.reduceToVectors({
  geometry: region, 
  scale: 11132,
})
var centroids = vectors
  .map(function (feature) {
    return ee.Feature(feature.geometry().centroid(1000)) 
      .copyProperties(feature)
  })
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/13fc78ccc9aedd28c5d8774b8a3843f0